# "Between" operator for jQuery QueryBuilder

Tags: jquery, query-builder

I'm implementing Mistic's [QueryBuilder](http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/), and find myself in need of a "between" operator. QueryBuilder provides a wide range of operators like equals, begins with, is not in, and such, but no "between". I know it can handle complex combinations of fields, so I'm sure it's possible to do.

I'm tantalized by the linked selects in the [widget demo](http://mistic100.github.io/jQuery-QueryBuilder/demo-widgets.html), but those combine two visible HTML inputs into one field that uses the existing operators. That is, it gives one select box for A/B/C, and one for 1/2/3, and yields a field value of "A.2" or "B.4" plus the selected equals/is not/whatever operator.

What I want is to show two text inputs, and, from them, generate a single query structure of "fieldname is greater than or equal to X AND fieldname is less than or equal to Y".

Does anyone have this code already, or know where to find it? I'm going to give it a shot, but I'm not a JS or jQuery person at all, so I may not succeed. If I do, I'll certainly post the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GitHub, [Feature #44 *(Operator "between")*](https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/44) was for exactly this.

Now when you define a field as being either a *Number* or a *Date*, it will have two fields where you can define what the field's value should be between.